# Error when calling PdfFontFactory.CreateFont, System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly in c# WebApp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-webpages, itext7

When calling

```
PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
```

or

```
PdfFontFactory.CreateFont();
```

inside a web application, target framework 4.0, I get following error.

```
[NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]
   System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_Location() +52
   iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil.<LoadITextResourceAssemblies>b__3(Assembly a) +30
   System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +115
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +239
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
   iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil.LoadITextResourceAssemblies() +172
   iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil..cctor() +125

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception.]
   iText.IO.Font.Type1Parser.GetMetricsFile() +127
   iText.IO.Font.Type1Font.Process() +53
   iText.IO.Font.Type1Font..ctor(String metricsPath, String binaryPath, Byte[] afm, Byte[] pfb) +131
   iText.IO.Font.FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(String name, Byte[] fontProgram, Boolean cached) +381
   iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(String fontProgram, String encoding) +29
   iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(String fontProgram) +31
   PdfCreator.x(String pdf_file_name) in x.cs:165
   ASP.x_cshtml.Execute() in x.cshtml:40
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +196
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +68
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +151
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +114
```

I thought I could work around the problem only using

```
PdfFontFactory.Register(windows_fonts + "ARIAL.TTF", "Arial");
PdfFont Arial = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("Arial");
```

but that will result only in a blank PDF without an error though.

When I run the same code in a c# console app I get a valid PDF with all the fonts.
Also the c# console app targets .net 4, so I am quite positive that it has nothing to do with the target framework. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: There is a bug in C# version of the library. Please see this pull requests for details how to fix it locally, or wait for a fix from iText team: https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/pull/2

Comment: Thank you, now I understand my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText team has released a special `.NET` version `7.0.2.2` with the fix for the described problem. This version is basically just the `7.0.2` version with the hotfix. There will be no `7.0.2.2` for Java because the problem only occurred in `.NET` in some circumstances.

New `7.0.2.2` version can be downloaded from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/7.0.2.2) or from [iText Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/nuget/itext7).

Answer (score 2):

For iTextSharp:

1. Download your favorite font as *.ttf file
2. Create Font object from file:

   ```
   string path = Path.Combine(AppDataPath, "helvetica.ttf");
   BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(path, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED); 
   Font font = new Font(baseFont, fontSize, Font.NORMAL);
   ```
3. Use this object when add elements to document:

   ```
   var p = new Paragraph("hello there!", font);
   doc.Add(p);
   ```

For iText7 look this [example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/clone-czech-example). Format is very similar, but use another class to create font:

```
   PdfFont f1 = PdfFontFactory.createFont(ttf_file_path, "Cp1250", true);
   Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Testing of letters").setFont(f1);
   doc.add(p1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply since you posted in iText5 Syntax, does that mean when using c# webpages one should stick to iText5 rather than iText7?

Comment: I use iTextSharp (https://github.com/itext/itextsharp), iText is another library of the same company (https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet). I have no experience with iText.

Comment: Your code does not throw an exception but the resulting pdf has no characters. I just cannot figure out why every function works apart from the PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(); I guess once that function works I will be able to get other fonts to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in C# version of the library. Please see this pull requests for details how to fix it locally, or wait for a fix from iText team: [github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/pull/2](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/pull/2) – Alexey Subach Mar 9 at 18:20